# Make Cloud Functions communicate with client - swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Till now I've only seen `cloud functions Firestore triggers` change values in backend server,
but is it possible to communicate from cloud functions to the client and make changes in the UI accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for a Cloud Function to pro-actively, directly call into your application code. But there are a few options though:

1. Call Firebase Cloud Messaging from your Cloud Function to send a message to your client-side application. Your application code can then either update the UI if the user is actively using the app, or it can show a notification otherwise. For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [notifying the user when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens).
2. If you only want the app to react to communications when the user is actively using it, you can set up a collection or document with messages for that user. For example: if you create a collection `messagesForStackGU` and you [listen for changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) in that collection, then any time something is written to that collection, your app will get notified and can update the UI.
3. You can also [call Functions directly from within your code](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/functions/usage#calling-endpoints). In such a case, you application code calls the server, which then responds. This is useful when the application code/the user initiates an action, that requires some work to happen on the server.

There may be more options, but these cover the broad categories available.